# How to remove SFSafariViewController as a child view controller correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am using the technique provided by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356986/830098) to preload some URL in SFSafariViewController like this:

```
addChildViewController(svc)
svc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
view.addSubview(svc.view)
```

And I try to remove the Safari View controller with following code:

```
svc.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
svc.view.removeFromSuperview()
svc.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Now I can preload the URL and show the Safari View without problem. However, after I repeat the process (preload/show/remove) several times (probably 30+ times) , the app will crash due to some memory issue because the log shows `Memory level is not normal or this app was killed by jetsam` when the app crashes.

Before crash, I saw some logs about possible-leak warnings:

```
<Warning>: notify name "UIKeyboardSpringBoardKeyboardShow" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak

<Warning>: notify name "com.apple.SafariViewService-com.apple.uikit.viewService.connectionRequest" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak
```

Am I doing it correctly when removing the Safari View controller? Am I missing something? Or any suggestion to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your adding child view controller code is as you have specified above then I think its order should be a bit different as per the documentation.

```
addChildViewController(svc)
view.addSubview(svc.view)
svc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

You should first add the child view and then call didMoveToParentViewController. Try this and see if it works.

> Listing 5-1Adding a child view controller to a container
>
> - (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content {    [self addChildViewController:content];    content.view.frame = [self
>   frameForContentController];    [self.view
>   addSubview:self.currentClientView];    [content
>   didMoveToParentViewController:self]; }
>
> In the preceding example, notice that you call only the
> didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child. That is because
> the addChildViewController: method calls the child’s
> willMoveToParentViewController: method for you. **The reason that you
> must call the didMoveToParentViewController: method yourself is that
> the method cannot be called until after you embed the child’s view
> into your container’s view hierarchy.**

Comment: tried the order suggested, but still the same problem remains.

Comment: Would yoube able to use a WKWebkitView and add it as a subview to your main VC instead of using SVC?

Comment: Can you send the whole code to me for testing or a sample prototype that demonstrates this issue?

Answer (score 1):

you are probably leaking `svc`. nil it out after removing it.

```
svc.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
svc.view.removeFromSuperview()
svc.removeFromParentViewController()
svc = nil
```

if this doesn't solve it, try enabling zombies or use the leaks instrument