# Can I preload the web content for Safari View Controller? - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

I try this: [Can I preload the web content for Safari View Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129632/can-i-preload-the-web-content-for-safari-view-controller)
but done button on SFSafariVC not working

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: self.SiteURL)!)
self.presentViewController(self.svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is swift version of [Can I preload the web content for Safari View Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129632/can-i-preload-the-web-content-for-safari-view-controller) (for me not working Done Button)

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: self.SiteURL)!)

    addChildViewController(svc)
    svc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    svc.view.frame = view.frame
    containerView.frame = view.frame
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    safariView = svc.view
    view.addSubview(safariView!)
    view.addSubview(containerView)

    view.sendSubviewToBack(safariView!)
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported with the current implementation of `SFSafariViewController`. Your best option right now is to use `WKWebView` and begin loading before it's added to the hierarchy.